# MongoDB Beanie, get one entry on list

Tags: python, mongodb

I have this model:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr
    first_name: str
    last_name: str

class Document (Document):
    course: int
    user: list[User]
```

I build query:

```
q = await Document.find_one(Document.course == 1,
                        Document.user.email == "user1@mail.com",
                        Document.user.last_name == "Don", )
```

How to properly query to return only one user?
THX!

Answer (score 0):

the `find_one` method on Beanie objects will return a single document if it exists in the mongo database which match all criteria provided (in this case, the criteria that needs to be matched would be: course = 1, email = user1@mail.com & last_name = Don)

Answer (score 0):

In beanie u can't query like this, to acheive this u have to write a query like:-

```
q = await Document.find_one({'course':1})
if q is not None:
   x=q.user
   for i in x:
      if i['email']== "user1@mail.com" and i["lastname"]=="Don":
         return q
```